# List products from selected categories and price range

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am really new in mysql and can't understand well what is the proper way to solve my issue, so if someone has a clue or a solution, it's more than welcome, here we go.

**I have two tables in my DB:**

**products:**

- id_product
- name_product
- etc...

**product_category:**

- id_product
- category_name

**When I save a product with more than one category it looks like this in my DB:**

```
id_product  category_name
1           kids
1           men
```

**In my html, I have a form like this:**

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="getcats"  value="Women">Women</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="getcats" value="Men">Men</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="getcats" value="Kids">Kids</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="range">
  € <input type="number" min="0" id="min" name="min" class="form-control" placeholder="0"> 
  € <input type="number" min="0" id="max" name="max" class="form-control" placeholder="100">
 </div>
 <button class="boton" id="request" onclick="request()">Request</button>
```

**Then in my JS file where I make the ajax call:**

```
function request(){

  //get the values from price range
  var min = jQuery("#min").val();
  var max = jQuery("#max").val();

  //create array to save the selected categories
  var categories = [];

  //save all the selected categories into the array
  jQuery('.getcats').each(function(){

    if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")){
        categories.push(jQuery(this).val());
    }

  });

  jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'request.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data:{
            categories:categories,
            min:min,
            max:max
        },
        success: function(data){
            //on success, display data requested
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }); // End of ajax call 

}
```

**And finally in my php file:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/javascript");

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../../config.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

//here should be some code to validate price range (min and max)

//after validation assign to variables
$min = $_POST["min"];
$max = $_POST["max"]; 

//here some code to validate selected categories (checkboxes)

//after validation assign to variable

$categories = $_POST["categories"];

$categoriesList = implode("','",$Intersectedresult); //$intersectedresult comes from array_intersect($categorias,$checkCategorias)
$resultList = "'".$categoriasList."'";

//Before I had this query working well but only when a product had 1 category, but now each product can have more than 1 category so I don't know how to make that query
$randomProducts = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_name IN ($resultList) && product_price BETWEEN $min AND $max ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3")

?>
```

I was researching a little and found some terms such as INNER JOIN but can't understand how to implement it to be able to do something like this:

```
$randomProducts = $conn->query("SELECT products.product_name, products.product_image, products.product_desc, products.product_url, products.product_price FROM products INNER JOIN product_category ON product_category.category_name=women, kids or men");
```

Hope someone can give me a push, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
WHERE p.id_product IN (
 SELECT pc.id_product
 FROM product_category pc
 AND pc.category_name IN ($resultList)
)
AND p.product_price BETWEEN $min AND $max ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Hi Alberto, Thanks for helping. I am trying your code and I'm getting this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in` at this line after I make the query: `while($row = $randomProducts->fetch_assoc()){` Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

you can use inner join or sub query concept.
 In answer 1 sub query is used and you can try this,..

This is link to understand inner join

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

You can try this also

`SELECT products.product_name, products.product_image, products.product_desc, products.product_url, products.product_price FROM products INNER JOIN product_category ON table name.table filed=table name.table field`
 (that you are going to compare mostly it is id of two tables)

Answer (score 0):

Use in your query `GROUP BY id_product`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    products
WHERE   category_name
    IN  ($resultList)
    AND product_price BETWEEN $min AND $max

GROUP   BY id_product
ORDER   BY rand()
LIMIT   3
```

Comment: Hi Geraldo, thanks for helping. As I mentioned in the post, the query I was using before could work only for products with 1 category, that's you can see the `WHERE category_name` but now I have products with multiples categories and those categories are saved into a different table. So that's my problem, how can I make a query like the last php code I have in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
from    product                     as PRD
        inner join product_category as CAT on PRD.id = CAT.id_product

where   CAT.category_name in ('woman', 'kids')
```